# how am ı use python websocket

Tags: python, websocket

ı am a begginer programmer so ı want to do some projects and ı have to use the websocket for python ı wrote import websocket but there is an ModuleNotFoundError:no module named "websocket"
How am ı have to import websocket module please help.

Comment: Have you *installed* the websocket module? If you haven't already you might want to read through [some of the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

In python, the library is called "socket":

```
import socket
```

Answer (score 0):

Mustafa,

It seems like you don't even have the module.

Download the module or install it with pip, and then you are going to be able to import it in your project.

```
pip install websocket_client
```

Then open python and try the following:

```
import websocket
```

Answer (score 0):

yes that was the problem for me because i didn't know how to install pip, but now ı learned thank you so much